# How to make mainactivity as home fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` and other `Fragments` which open a `WebView` when user clicks on them on `NavigationViewer`. I added Home `Fragment` to navigation view but I don't know how to make it default so that if user opens the App, default home `Fragment` opens up. Do I have to make another Java class or use `MainActivity`. Java as home? If yes, how do I use `MainActivity`. Java as home `Fragment`? And if user clicks other `Fragment` to open a `WebView` and presses the backbutton, how to make it go back to the default home `Fragment`? At the moment, if I press the backbutton, it literally destroys App and goes back to Phone background.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Launcher-Activity which has a fragment provider to set the content, you may want to store the default fragment somehow.

Usually you start your activity and have a [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) which replaces a part of your content with a fragment.

If you want to have a changing behaviour depending on a logic, you want to store the starting fragment with Ids or similar using SharedPreferences or any other storing technologie like SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are changing between fragments in `onNavigationItemSelected` using a `FragmentManager` similar to this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment);
ft.commit();
```

If you want to open Fragment when the activity starts, what you have to is exactly same as  to what you do in `onNavigationItemSelected`, you have to call `FragmentManager` on `onCreate` and also make the item on the `NavigationView` selected:

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home_fragment);
```

As for back button, you should override `onBackPressed`function. If you use Navigation Drawer template from Android Studio, it should be:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

You can simply add your logic in the else part, you can keep track of the active Fragment by keeping a reference to it/looking from FragmentManager (or looking the selected item of Navigation Drawer) and make it behave accordingly:

```
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame)
if(currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment)
    super.onBackPressed();
else {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First set some kind of "Container" in your `MainActivity` `Layout` which will contain the `Fragment`:

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/indications_LL"
            >
</FrameLayout>
```

Then set the `FragmentManager` and the `FragmentTransaction`:

```
private FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

if you want to start with the main `Fragment` in your `onCreate()` method 
add the code below:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new MainFragment(), *"set Tag for your fragment"*);
```

Don't forget to add the Fragment to the BackStack:

```
ragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(*"Your Fragment Tag"*)
```

**Take a look at my Example code below:**

```
/**
 * A fragment transaction Method
 *
 * @param fragment the fragment we want to display
 */
private void setFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, MainMenus tagName) {


    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 

    //replacing fragments new Fragments
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tagName.toString());
    } else if (fragment == null && (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)) { // starting with main Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new MainFragment(), MainMenus.MAIN_MENUS.toString());
    }
    if (tagName == null) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tagName.toString());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

For the `backbutton` you must `@Override` the `onBackPressed()` method. Then you can handle the backPress using the `Fragment's TAG` or you can `popBackStack()` when it reach to specific Fragment's count: 
Take a look at the Example below:

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

    //The first method, using TAG
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( * "Your Fragment TAG" *.toString()) !=null){
                fragmentManager.popBackStack()
            }


    //The second method: if more than two fragment, delete fragment stack
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 3) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
super.onBackPressed();
        }
```